# Doctrine 2 association overwrite

Tags: php, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm, associations

I have a question about Doctrine 2 and the ability (or not?) to extend an association between to classes.

Best explained with an example :)

Let's say I have this model (code is not complete):

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class User {
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group")
     * @var Group[]
     */
    protected $groups;
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Group {
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role")
     * @var Role[]
     */
    protected $roles;
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Role {
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="RoleType")
     * @var RoleType
     */
    protected $type;
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class RoleType {
    public function setCustomDatas(array $params) {
        // do some stuff. Default to nothing
    }
}
```

Now I use this model in some projects. Suddenly, in a new project, I need to have a RoleType slightly different, with some other fields in DB and other methods. Of course, it was totally unexpected.

What I do in the "view-controller-but-not-model" code is using services:

```
// basic configuration
$services['RoleType'] = function() {
    return new RoleType();
};

// and then in the script that create a role
$role_type = $services['RoleType'];
$role_type->setCustomDatas($some_params);
```

During application initialization, I simply add this line to overwrite the default RoleType

```
$services['RoleType'] = function() {
    return new GreatRoleType();
};
```

Ok, great! I can customize the RoleType call and then load some custom classes that do custom things.

But... now I have my model. The model says that a Role targets a RoleType. And this is hard-written. Right now, to have my custom changes working, I need to extend the Role class this way:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class GreatRole extends Role {
    /**
     * Changing the targetEntity to load my custom type for the role
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="GreatRoleType")
     * @var RoleType
     */
    protected $type;
}
```

But then, I need to extend the Group class to target GreatRole instead of Role.
And in the end, I need to extend User to target GreatGroup (which targets GreatRole, which targets GreatRoleType).

Is there a way to avoid this cascade of extends? Or is there a best practice out there that is totally different from what I did?

Do I need to use [MappedSuperClasses](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasse)? The doc isn't very explicit...

Thanks for your help!

--------------------------- EDIT ---------------------------

If I try to fetch all the hierarchy from User, that's when I encounter problems:

```
$query
    ->from('User', 'u')
    ->leftJoin('u.groups', 'g')
    ->leftJoin('g.roles', 'r')
    ->leftJoin('r.type', 't');
```

If I want to have a "r.type" = GreatRoleType, I need to redefine each classes.

Comment: Sorry, why do you feel that you need to add a 'GreatGroup' class? Since your 'GreatRole' class extends 'Role' class it should still be able to be accepted into '$roles' variable..

Comment: Well, because when I fetch a User, I would like to join Group, Role and RoleType. If I change the last for GreatRoleType, I will need to update the whole chain of joins. Because ->from('User', 'u')->leftJoin('u.groups', 'g')->leftJoin('g.roles', 'r')->leftJoin('r.type', 't'); will fetch explicitely User, Group, Role and RoleType.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, I am not that familiar with doctrine2, so I cannot offer ready answer. But it seems to me that your question is a database design question. What you need to do is sit down and draw your current mapping and see how the new GreatRole class affects your model. Does the new GreatRole class introduce new attributes, which are not there in Role class? How are you using these classes? After that you can choose which method of inheritance to use - maybe you can still store everything in the same table, or maybe you need separate tables for each class.